# Google Map Update dynamically in Angular

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

http://plnkr.co/edit/Zd9GwG?p=preview

I am working on this google map + angular.js example . I want to change the location center dynamically depend on the variable .i.e. I want to make it dynamic center. Please suggest how to do this ?

I want to do some thing Like this.

// Code goes here

```
//Add the requried module 'angular-ui' as a dependency
angular.module('maptesting', ['ui.directives']);

function MapCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.lat = 35.120922 ;
  $scope.long = -89.97731 ;
    var ll = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.lat, $scope.long);
    $scope.mapOptions = {
        center: ll,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    //Markers should be added after map is loaded
    $scope.onMapIdle = function() {
        //alert("DF");
        if ($scope.myMarkers === undefined){    
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: $scope.myMap,
                position: ll
            });
            $scope.myMarkers = [marker, ];
        }
    };
       $scope.showMarkerInfo = function(marker) {  
        $scope.myInfoWindow.open($scope.myMap, marker);
    };

    $scope.changeval = function(){
      $scope.lat = 13.0810 ;
      $scope.long = 80.2740 ;


    };





}
```

Comment: what should be dynamic? the center of the map? the marker? more details please.

Comment: Why closed ? I edited the question. I need answer sir

Answer (score 8):

**You need to watch for changes in the scope in order to refresh the map.**

## [Demo Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nF0CO1G9l0G7AtHkymGZ?p=preview)

(just use the input fields above the map to change the center of the map in real time)

The important part is `$scope.$watch`:

```
  var updateCenter = function() {
    var ll = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.lat, $scope.long);
    $scope.myMap.panTo(ll);
    // eventually more stuff
  }
  $scope.$watch('lat', updateCenter);
  $scope.$watch('long', updateCenter);
```

Comment: Nice .is there any way to show direction between two location ?

Comment: It is working fine in Browser but in phoneGap - Ios the marker is not showing

Comment: You need to look through the API documentation of Google Maps for such basic questions.

Comment: I am sorry for such question, but I see you use array in positioning the location : `[marker, ]`, did it means that after the comma I can push another variable of array? If yes, can you show me an example of two location?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand your question. Can you please create a demo plunkr with your problem?